# woocommerce api access error 404

Tags: wordpress, api

I have encounter 404 always in woocommerce api access
I set my permalink into post-name
I have 2.5.2 version woocommerce
I have no firewall problem

but when i type 
https://www.example.com/wc-api/v3/products
no matter with my consumer key and secret or not
it has 404 problem. I cannot access the door file of woocommerce api at all

Do anybody have any ideas to help me enter the woocommerce API?
I am really of gratitude of your help

Best regards

Comment: can you please tell me are you created 404.php page or not

Answer (score 1):

Try going to `Settings -> Permalinks` on the Admin Panel.
In the `Default Settings` radio group, select the "Post name" one.
Save the changes.

Comment: thank you very much for your help. but I am not sure i have done what you recommended exactly. I go to Settings -> Permalink and I only see common settings, optional and product permalink. The permalink is always like: http://www.mggab.se/index.php/sample-post/ . but it does not work. and i do not understand what is ratio group you mentioned. But thanks a lot for your replying

Comment: but anyway my selection is post name right now. but it does not work

Comment: Can you replace it with post id in permalink

Comment: changed to mggab.se/index.php/%post-id%/ still not working

Comment: check your .htaccess file please

Answer (score 0):

Please check your API endpoints. You have used `wc-api/<version code>`. In the latest version of woocommerce it's `/wp-json/wc`.

Check this document here for reference:
https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/?php#request-response-format.

Hope that helps...
Best of Luck
Cheerz,
Big J